# Get the number of pages in a Mediawiki (Wikipedia) namespace

Tags: mediawiki

So there is [AllPages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Allpages) API which allows one to enumerate all pages in a Mediawiki namespace. But how can one just get a count of pages in a namespace? I am interested in the count primarily so that I can show a progress bar for the `AllPages` API call which can take quite some time.

There is [Siteinfo](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Siteinfo) which has some statistics, but is is not at the same granularity as namespaces.

Comment: A opened an issue: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T312200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a proper API for it. There's the [`{{PAGESINNAMESPACE}}` magic word](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Statistics) (disabled by default), which can be used with the [parse API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext). Or you can use the [search API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search) with nothing but a namespace filter - how well that works might depend on what search backend you are using.

Comment: Is it enabled on English Wikipedia and Wikimedia Commons? Is there a way to detect if magic word is enabled?

Comment: You can check via `action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=variables`. It's not enabled on large Wikimedia wikis.

Comment: `srsearch` seems to be required. Wikimedia wikis seem to use CirrusSearch, so what would be a query string to match everything?

Comment: You can exclude something impossible, like `-contentmodel:fake`.